# How to render URL strings as clickable hyperlink in the Neo4j Browser?

Tags: neo4j

Does anyone know if there is a trick to do that?
Url strings are not rendered as clickable hrefs. I've tried to add html inside the property but it doesn't work either. It seems that there used to be a branch for that https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/pull/43 but hasn't been merged I think.

Comment: We could add it to github.com/jexp/spoon-neo4j

Comment: That would be great!